# calcular el salario mensual de un vendedor

Tags: javascript

Estoy tratando de crear una función de flecha que resuelva el siguiente problema.

PROBLEMA: Watto paga a su personal de ventas un salario de 3500000 mensuales, más una comisión de 1500000 por cada licencia de software vendida menos el 5% de deducciones por impuestos. Codifica un programa que calcule e imprima el salario mensual de un vendedor dado;

Este es el código que he realizado

```
let calcular = ()=>{

let salario = 3500000;
let comicion = 1500000;
let licencia = 3;
let salarioCom = 0;

salarioCom = (licencia * comicion)+ salario;
salarioDe = salarioCom * 0.05;
salarioNeto = salarioCom - salarioDe;

console.log(salarioNeto);

}
```

Comment: Hola. ¿Que error te da?, además una función de flecha debe ser declarada como `const`, en tu caso `const calcular = ()=>{...}`

Comment: No me imprime nada

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Las funciones flechas se declaran de manera similar a las variables, declarando primero el identificador de variable (`const`, `let` o `var`), luego el nombre de la función, el signo de igual (`=`), los argumentos entre paréntesis y luego el cuerpo de la función. En general:

```
const nombreDeLaFuncion = (argumentos) => {// código}
```

Basado en el problema, el salario mensual es una cantidad fija y solo varía dependiendo de la cantidad de licencias que venda un empleado. Tu función entonces tomará como único parámetro **la cantidad de licencias vendidas**, e imprimirá y devolverá el salario mensual.

El salario mensual es el salario base (3500000), más la comisión por licencia (1500000) menos el 5% del total. O lo que es lo mismo, el 95% de todo lo que ganó, que se puede escribir como:

```
salario = (3500000 + 1500000*licenciasVendidas)*0.95
```

Finalmente, poniendo los requerimientos en dentro de una función flecha, quedaría:

```js
const salarioMensual = (licenciasVendidas = 0) => {
   const salario = (3500000 + 1500000*licenciasVendidas)*0.95
   console.log(salario)
   return salario
}

salarioMensual()
salarioMensual(1)
```

Comment: Responder sólo con código se considera de baja calidad. Tienes la reputación suficiente para saber esto. Te sugiero editar tu respuesta y agregar una explicación de porqué tu código sería una respuesta válida a la pregunta. De momento tienes mi -1.

Comment: @MauricioContreras ya edité mi respuesta. La pregunta es bastante trivial, pero de cualquier manera agregué una explicación.

Comment: Muy bien, ahora tienes mi +1, por tu esfuerzo en mantener el orden del sitio. Saludos